# How to make a div move slowly with inline-block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to remove the div `redBoxId` when `blueBoxId` div is clicked. On css side, I have `inline-block` as a property since it automatically centers itself to the parent div. However, I want to add an effect(transition??) where when the `redBoxId` is removed, the`blueBoxId` **slowly/smoothly** moves instead of quick movement(while keeping inline-block as a css property).

```js
document.getElementById('blueBoxId').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('blueBoxId').style.transition = "all 2s ease-in-out";
  document.getElementById('redBoxId').remove();
})
```

```css
#redBoxId {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blueBoxId {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="redBlueBox">
  <div id="redBoxId">hi</div>
  <div id="blueBoxId">hi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Comment: You can just set the opacity to 0 and then remove it after that transition has occurred. You can also apply your transition CSS on #blueBoxId in your CSS file because having it applied after the click doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Want it in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `transition` in the `css` and you can't apply the transition on the `remove`, shrink he width and / or the opacity, then remove the element once the animation ends,

```js
document.getElementById('blueBoxId').addEventListener('click', function(){
    
    document.getElementById('redBoxId').style.width = 0;
    document.getElementById('redBoxId').style.opacity = 0;
    
    /*
    * optional if you want remove the DOM and not just hide it
    *
     setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById('redBoxId').remove();
     }, 1000);
    */
})
```

```css
#redBoxId{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

#blueBoxId{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="redBlueBox">
   <div id="redBoxId">hi</div>
   <div id="blueBoxId">hi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to `remove()`, add overflow hidden to the red and vertical align both boxes to top

Comment: yes, but i just wanted to make as minimal as possible to the OP's snippet,

Comment: I think it's more flexible if you decouple the js timeout period from the css transition time. Plus you mentioned "and/or opacity", if you don't use `remove()` and not changing opacity, you will need overflow hidden which will force the use of vertical align. If you use remove() without opacity, there is going to be a little bit of unwanted transition without overflow hidden

Answer (score 1):

I used visibility to remove the red box first, then set its width to 0. Now, the bluebox isn't animating, the animation/transition is on the red box as its width decreases, but because the visibility is hidden so you don't see it.

I set the transition time to 0.5s, this you can edit it to whatever you want. The other answer works as well, I am just giving you another option for the transition.

This method uses a css class instead of doing the css in js.

You could also combine the class addition with the other answer's css to achieve the same thing

```js
document.getElementById('blueBoxId').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('redBoxId').classList.add("remove");
});
```

```css
#redBoxId {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#blueBoxId {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#redBoxId.remove {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="redBlueBox">
  <div id="redBoxId">hi</div>
  <div id="blueBoxId">hi</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with eventually. Since I did not wanted fade kind of effect on the red box and wanted it to disappear instantly on click:

```
document.getElementById('blueBoxId').addEventListener('click', function(){

  //added white background//
  document.getElementById('redBoxId').style.background = "white"; 

  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('redBoxId').style.transition = "0.5s"
    document.getElementById('redBoxId').style.width = 0;
  }, 100);

 //remove the div from the dom//
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('redBoxId').remove();
  }, 1000);
})
```

css:

```
#redBoxId{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
 }

#blueBoxId{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
 }
```